# PL SQL CURSOR FUNCTION

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, database-cursor

How to write a cursor that fills out missing primary key values in a sequence?

For example, ids: 1,3,4,5,7 are present and the function will insert 2 and 6.

We know the max(id) and have a function that can find the next missing value of primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

If this is table contents:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID
----------
         1
         3
         4
         5
         7
```

then - using one of row generator techniques - create the whole set (lines #6 - 8) and apply the `MINUS` set operator to find missing values:

```
SQL> with
  2  minimax as
  3    (select min(id) minid, max(id) maxid
  4     from test
  5    )
  6  select minid + level - 1 id
  7  from minimax
  8  connect by level <= maxid - minid + 1
  9  minus
 10  select id from test;

        ID
----------
         2
         6

SQL>
```

Now it is simple to insert them:

```
SQL> insert into test (id)
  2  with
  3  minimax as
  4    (select min(id) minid, max(id) maxid
  5     from test
  6    )
  7  select minid + level - 1 id
  8  from minimax
  9  connect by level <= maxid - minid + 1
 10  minus
 11  select id from test;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Can you modify this to not allow for duplicates?

Comment: This query - as is - doesn't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
    v_max number;
    v_count number;
begin
select max(id) into v_max from test_table;
for i in 1..v_max loop
    select count(*) into v_count from test_table where id=i;
    if v_count>0 then 
        null;
    else 
        insert into test_table (id) values (i);
    end if;
end loop;
end;
```

and if u want a procedure to do it dinamicaly like this:

```
exec inser_id(table_name,column_name);
```

then the code is:

```
create or replace procedure inser_id (p_table_name varchar2, p_column_name varchar2) as
    v_max number;
    v_count number;
    v_table_name varchar2(32):=p_table_name;
    v_column_name varchar2(32):= p_column_name;
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max('||v_column_name||') from '||v_table_name
into v_max;
for i in 1..v_max loop
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from ' ||v_table_name||' where id='||i
    into v_count;
    if v_count=0 then 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into ' ||v_table_name||' ('||v_column_name||') values ('||i||')';
    end if; 
end loop;
end;
```